# Pairwise substraction of multiindexed columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd dataframe of this type (multiindex in the columns):

```
    measurement meas1           meas2            ...
    observer    obs1 obs2       obs1 obs2        ...

1               1   1           1    1
2               2   1           6    3  
3               2   3           3    2
```

The column index is unique.
I want to create a dataframe of differences between the observers for every measurement:

```
 measurement    meas1           meas2            ...
 observerpair   (obs1,obs2)     (obs1,obs2)        ...

1               0                  0
2               1                  3  
3               -1                 1
```

I have tried two different for-loops to create the difference-dataframe. This is inside:

```
data[('meas1','obs1')].subtract(data[('meas1','obs2')])
```

or

```
data[('meas1','obs1')] - data[('meas1','obs2')]
```

I can display every single column by itself, but whenever I do one of the two computations, I get a result like that:

```
    measurement meas1           
    observer    obs1 obs2       

1               NaN NaN           
2               NaN NaN            
3               NaN NaN
```

I have tried this for another dataframe of the same structure (generated automatically by the same script), this issue never occured. As I mentioned, I checked the columns by themselves, they look normal when called like that:

```
data[('meas1','obs1')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select column in `MultiIndex` and [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
df1 = df.xs('obs1', axis=1, level=1).sub(df.xs('obs2', axis=1, level=1))
print (df1)
measurement  meas1  meas2
1                0      0
2                1      3
3               -1      1
```

If want `MultiIndex` in output add [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df1 = df.xs('obs1', axis=1, level=1).sub(df.xs('obs2', axis=1, level=1))
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['obs1,obs2']], 
                                         names=df.columns.names)
print (df1)
measurement      meas1     meas2
observerpair obs1,obs2 obs1,obs2
1                    0         0
2                    1         3
3                   -1         1
```